# How to import an icon already imported from another file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I have a *data.js* file which stores several information. I would like to store an icon imported from this file and to be able to access it from another to display this icon. How can I proceed?

data.js

```
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';

const navigation = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        icon: HomeIcon,
    },
];

export { navigation };
```

myComponent.js

```
import { navigation } from 'Src/api/data';

const NavBar = () => {
    const Icon = navigation[0].icon;

    return <Icon/>;
};

export default NavBar;
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What's the problem? What's not working? What's happening instead exactly?

Comment: The problem is that nothing is displayed. I get an empty tag that looks like this: <icon> </ icon>

I can not find any way to display my icon because it is not imported into the same file where I use it.

I hope to be as clear as possible, and thank you for your support!

Comment: I just tried your code as-is and it works, so you're not sharing a valid [mcve] in your question.

Comment: You're right Emile. In my code I did not have a capital letter on my component "Icon", it was simply named "icon" and should not be considered as a component properly spoken ...

Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much for your help, it's a pleasure and it motivates.